# Search and replace all elements

Tags: javascript

I need script to append text or delete all matched elements if there are any in textarea.
I tried this:
http://pastie.org/789631
What's wrong there? Thanks.

Comment: Well, basically this is what i meant:
http://pastie.org/789814
It works, but i would like it to perform like toggle: when the value i want is presented it should delete it otherwise it should add it. How could i do that?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
txt.replaceText(RegExp(elem,"g"), '');
```